# .FindPrevious not finding the true previous in excel userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a userform in Excel to be able to search for scientific papers based on search terms such as "Author name". My userform has a `cmdSearch` button ("Author Search") that allows the user to type in the Author's name and find the first record matching that search. Control boxes representing fields such as Author names, title, abstract, etc. are then populated from that row in the Excel file. I have tried to add a `cmdNext` and `cmdPrevious` button to the form to continue searching forward to each row that has the same Author name or to go back to the previously viewed record. To do this I have implemented a loop function using `.find` and `.findnext` to go forward and `.find` and `.findprevious` to go backwards. To stop the infinite loop I have put in a `Do While Not... Loop` with "Continue Next" and "Continue Previous" buttons that you must click to be able to view the subsequent record. (There may be a slightly more elegant way to do this, but this is not my question at present.)

The problem I am encountering is that when you click the `cmdPrevious` button ("Previous"), rather than going to the last record viewed (the truly previous record), it goes to the second to last record in the data set. What I think is happening is that `.find` is locating the last record in the dataset and `.findprevious` is then going to the record previous to that. Below is my current code for the `cmdPrevious` loop. Can anyone suggest how to modify my code to get it to search for the most recently viewed record?

**Note**: I have tried to use `Worksheets("literature_format").Activate` and then `After:= ActiveCell.Row` so that I can start my `.find` command after the current row, but this does not work (the code does not function - nothing happens when I click the button). Further, if I use `MsgBox ActiveCell.Row` to see what it considers the active row, it always returns the row of the very first record with that author's last name. That is, even after I have started searching forward or backward so that my form does not show the information from the first record, `ActiveCell.Row` always returns the same row number. Is there some trick to getting this to work and to get it to update what the "active row" is as I move through the dataset?

Here is my code for the Back button:

```
Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click()

Dim data As Range
Dim findrow As Range
Dim prevrow As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Search As String

On Error Resume Next

Set ws = Worksheets("literature_format")
Set data = Sheet1.Range("H:H")

Search = Me.txtSearch.Value

If Search = "" Then
    MsgBox "Search for previous record"
    Else

Set findrow = data.find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not findrow Is Nothing Then

        Set prevrow = findrow
        Do
            Set findrow = data.FindPrevious(After:=findrow)
            If Not findrow Is Nothing Then
            If findrow.Address = prevrow.Address Then Exit Do
            Me.Control1.Value = findrow.Offset(0, 0)
            Me.Control2.Value = findrow.Offset(0, 3)
            Me.Control3.Value = findrow.Offset(0, 4)
            Me.Control4.Value = findrow.Offset(0, 15)
            Me.Control5.Value = findrow.Offset(0, 2)
            Me.Control6.Value = findrow.Offset(0, -7)
            Me.Control7.Value = "Name of author(s)"

           Do While Not bprevious
                DoEvents

            Loop
            bprevious = False

            End If


        Loop
        MsgBox "First record"
        Exit Sub


    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Here if my code for the Continue Previous button (that stops the infinite loop), and uses a public variable As Boolean:

```
Public bprevious As Boolean

Private Sub cmdBackward_Click()

'used for continue previous loop
bprevious = True

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to modify my code to get it to search for the most recently viewed record would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using `Find()` doesn't change the ActiveCell: you would be better off storing a reference to the range in a global within your form.

Comment: Hi Tim, would you be able to show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: To be honest it's not clear how your code is structured ("There may be a slightly more elegant way to do this" - this is true), so it would take some time for me to figure that out. Your life would be easier if you perform the search only once, collecting *all* matches into an array or Collection of row numbers, which is then stored as a Global variable.  Your Prev/Next buttons just decrement/increment a number which tracks your current position in that collection and then call a generic "show row" sub which displays the content based on the row number.

Comment: Hmm interesting idea, I will work on that. Thanks for your input!